# SKAction playSoundFileNamed first played sound is clipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit scene. In the `didMoveToView` I have several sounds set up like this:

```
self.sound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed: @"one.wav" waitForCompletion: NO];
```

When I want to play the sound on an event, I do

```
[node runAction: self.sound];
```

The sounds plays ok, but the first sound I play from the scene is clipped i.e. can be described as a bit of a click/crackling sound. Sounds after this first sound play just fine. There's no slow down or stutter in the animation, just this odd clipping on the first sound played in the scene.

Anyone seen this?

Comment: Also see SKAction: error playing sound resource just for that first sound. Tried changing sounds to a caf file and same thing.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045057/sprite-kit-game-hickup-when-the-first-sound-is-played)

Comment: @appzYourLife he's already doing what's suggested there, so far as I can tell.

Comment: Do you have a chance to play a sound at zero volume, with code, prior to the need for a first sound? This forces the sounds to load, and the audio player to become active and loaded, which is probably what your first sound is doing, hence the little clipping.

Comment: Yes I'm already pre creating the skaction like that post suggests. I don't get a hiccup in the animation etc. I'll have a look at the zero volume suggestion

Comment: Playing the silent sound first solved this. Bit of a strange workaround but fixed the issue!